# Generic Pointers in C and memory allocation

Tags: c, void-pointers

How does the machine know how much space to allocate for a generic pointer? Is it only allocated when cast to a type?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you mean by a "generic pointer", but if you mean "pointer to void", it's simply a type capable of representing any other *pointer value*. This does not mean it has to be arbitrarily large; in fact it's (defined to be) the same size and representation as "pointer to character", which can also point to any type.

Answer (score 1):

On the majority of platforms pointers are generally of a fixed size based on the memory architecture of the system you are compiling for. Their type, with regard to that, is irrelevant. An `int` point is the same size as a point to a complex `struct`. The fact that it's `void` doesn't change this.

Comment: The C standard makes no statement that all pointers are to be of the same size, and on some archaic architectures, they're definitely not the same size (although I don't have any examples to hand).

Comment: Okay, so the absolute statement I had before was false, but would you say that holds true generally?

Comment: If you say something like "on the majority of platforms", then I think it would be ok.

Answer (score 1):

All pointers are of the size known to the compiler at compile time; it is the size of the item being pointed to that may be different. You pass the required size to `malloc`/`calloc` yourself, so the compiler has no problem with allocation.

**EDIT (in response to a comment)** There are cases when sizes of different pointers are different. For example, in the code compiled for Harvard architecture a data pointer must include an extra storage that distinguishes the data stored in program memory from the data stored in the data memory, while function pointers do not need that extra storage. However, this is known to the compiler, so it knows the required allocation size from looking at the type of the pointer.

Comment: C is not C++, discussion of templates doesn't belong here.

Comment: @VariableLengthCoder Oops, you'er right! I got thrown off by the mention of "generic" pointers.

Comment: I agree, OP's use of the undefined term "generic pointer" makes this question difficult to answer..

Comment: And this answer is still wrong; all pointers need not be of the same size. For instance on a PDP...

Comment: @R.. What PDP are you talking about? The PDP-11 kind was pretty uniform about the 16-bit pointer size; so was 68000. 6502, on the other hand, allowed "fast" access in the 0x00FF page with single-byte addresses. 8051 used three bytes per data pointer to distinguish data memory from program memory, but only two bytes for function pointers, because functions could not go into data memory.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, pointers pointed to a 16-bit word. To have a character pointer, you needed an extra bit...

Comment: @R.. Well, I remember that PDP-11 required different instructions for accessing a byte vs. accessing a word, and that the instructions differed by a single bit (I think the most significant bit of the instruction). But the access size was encoded in the instruction, not in the pointer itself.

Comment: Maybe it was some other machine then that lacked byte-access entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Pointers are all the same size no matter what they are pointing to, it's only the thing they are pointing to that can be different sizes.